# How can I access which stack item was pressed with KivyMD 1.1.1 in FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to use KivyMDs FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial, with something different happening depending on which stack button is pressed. Right now, I'm just trying to print which button was pressed. I can't find any examples in the documentation, and all the tutorials I find say to use:

''' callback: callback '''

But using callback doesn't print anything at all. How can I fix this?

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder


class My_FirstApp(MDApp):

  data = {
      "Python": "language-python",
      "Ruby":"language-ruby",
      "JS":"language-javascript"
  }

  def callback(self, instance):

      print("press")

      print(instance.icon)

  def open(self):

      print("Open")

      self.root.ids.my_label.text = f'Open!'

  def close(self):

      print("CLose")

      self.root.ids.my_label.text = f'Close!'


  def build(self):

      self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"

      self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"

      return Builder.load_file("SpeedDialButton.kv")


My_FirstApp().run()
```

##### Kivy file

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    Screen:
            MDLabel:
                    id: my_label

                    text: "Stuff"

                    halign: "center"

            MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:

                    data: app.data

                    root_button_anim: True

                    #PushTheButton

                    callback: app.callback

                    on_open: app.open()

                    on_close: app.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback was removed in v1.1, and you can now add more data to your data dictionary to call the on_press and on_release for the item clicked.

I.e.,

```
self.data = {
    'Python': [
        'language-python',
        "on_press", lambda x: self.item_pressed('Python'),
        "on_release", lambda x: self.item_released('Python')
    ],
}
```

.kv file

```
MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
    data: app.data
    root_button_anim: True
    on_open: app.open()
    on_close: app.close()
```

Here is your code updated to work with the new way of doing it.

SpeedDialButton.py

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    Screen:
        MDLabel:
            id: my_label
            text: "Stuff"
            halign: "center"

        MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
            data: app.data
            root_button_anim: True
            on_open: app.open()
            on_close: app.close()
```

main.py

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.properties import DictProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class My_FirstApp(MDApp):
    data = DictProperty()

    def item_pressed(self, name) -> None:
        print(f'Button pressed: {name}')

    def item_released(self, name) -> None:
        print(f'Button released: {name}')

    def open(self):
        print("Open")

        self.root.ids.my_label.text = f'Open!'

    def close(self):
        print("CLose")

        self.root.ids.my_label.text = f'Close!'

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"
        self.data = {
            'Python': [
                'language-python',
                "on_press", lambda x: self.item_pressed('Python'),
                "on_release", lambda x: self.item_released('Python')
            ],
            'Ruby': [
                'language-ruby',
                "on_press", lambda x: self.item_pressed('Ruby'),
                "on_release", lambda x: self.item_released('Ruby')
            ],
            'JS': [
                'language-javascript',
                "on_press", lambda x: self.item_pressed('JS'),
                "on_release", lambda x: self.item_released('JS')
            ],

        }
        return Builder.load_file("SpeedDialButton.kv")


My_FirstApp().run()
```